# How do I properly set method of derived class as callable for a parent class?

Tags: php, callback

I am writing a basic class with some call_user_func() and then derived class with a method I want to be called from said call_user_func(). It looks as follows:

```php
class Basic
{
    private $InputHandler = null;

    public function SetNewHandler(callable $NewHandler)
    {
        $this->InputHandler = $NewHandler;
    }

    public function ProcessInput()
    {
        call_user_func(array($this,$this->InputHandler));
    }
}

class Specific extends Basic
{
    public function Handler()
    {
        echo "Handler() is called\n";
    }
}

$spec = new Specific();
$spec->SetNewHandler('Specific\Handler');
$spec->ProcessInput();
unset($spec);
```

Obviously it does not work since `Specific\Handler` is not recognized as a valid callable.
But what is the proper way to achieve this outcome? Parent class should be oblivious to the details of implementation of derived class and\or handler method.

I use php 7.4

Comment: When adding the callback, pass it as an array with the real instance: `->setNewHandler([$spec, 'Handler'])` and then execute it with: `call_user_func($this->InputHandler)` and se if that works.

Comment: is `Specific` always a class and `Handler` always a method? the format of the string is `Class\Handler`?

Comment: @Raskul Yes. Yes. No. The format of the string can be arbitrary as long as it works as intended.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I shall see if it works a bit later, but the first thought is that I very much prefer (whenever possible) `callable` type hint in `SetNewHandler()` as it provides some degree of fool-proof coding.

Comment: _"The format of the string can be arbitrary as long as it works as intended"_ - Since you type hint it as [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), the string must follow specific predefined formats, which is _not_  arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a default handler method in the base class:

```
class Base
{
    public function ProcessInput()
    {
        $this->Handler();
    }

    public function Handler() 
    {
        // Some default code or just leave empty
        echo "Base Handler() is called\n";
    }
}

class Specific extends Base 
{
    public function Handler()
    {
        echo "Specific Handler() is called\n";
    }
}

$spec = new Specific;
$spec->ProcessInput();
```

This way you don't need to manually bind the handler you want to use for each instance (which could be cumbersome). If you want a new handler, create a new class with that handler.

Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/YA2d5)

Comment: Wow. Why didn't I think of such an elegant solution... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you made the call with call_user_func(array ($this, $this->InputHandler)); a method name is expected as the 2nd array element.

```
class Basic
{
    private $InputHandler = null;

    public function SetNewHandler($NewHandler)
    {
        $this->InputHandler = $NewHandler;
    }

    public function ProcessInput()
    {
        call_user_func(array($this,$this->InputHandler));
    }
}

class Specific extends Basic
{
    public function Handler()
    {
        echo "Handler() is called\n";
    }
}

$spec = new Specific();
$spec->SetNewHandler('Handler');
$spec->ProcessInput();
```

Instead of call_user_func(Array($this, $this->InputHandler)); does this work here too:

```
$method = $this->InputHandler;
$this->$method();
```

or this:

```
$this->{$this->InputHandler}();
```

Alternatively: A callable is passed similarly as described by @Magnus Eriksson in the comment.

```
class Basic
{
    private $InputHandler = null;

    public function SetNewHandler(callable $NewHandler)
    {
        $this->InputHandler = $NewHandler;
    }

    public function ProcessInput()
    {
        call_user_func($this->InputHandler);
                
    }
}

class Specific extends Basic
{
    public function Handler()
    {
        echo "Handler() is called\n";
    }
}

$spec = new Specific();
$spec->SetNewHandler([$spec,'Handler']);
$spec->ProcessInput();
```